# Alternatives to concatenating strings or going procedural to prevent SQL query code repetition?

Tags: query, dynamic-sql, scripting

Disclaimer: Please bear with me as someone who only uses databases a tiny fraction of his work time. (Most of the time I do C++ programming in my job, but every odd month I need to search/fix/add something in an Oracle database.)

I have repeatedly needed to write complex SQL queries, both for ad-hoc queries and for queries built into applications, where large parts of the queries where just repeated "code".

Writing such abominations in a traditional programming language would get you in deep trouble, yet I (**I**) have yet been unable to find any decent technique to prevent SQL query code repetition.

---

**Edit:** 1st, I want to thank the answerers who provided excellent improvements to my original *example*. However, this question is not about my example. It's about repetitiveness in SQL queries. As such, the answers ([JackP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/alternatives-to-concatenating-strings-or-going-procedural-to-prevent-sql-query-co/2712#2712), [Leigh](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/alternatives-to-concatenating-strings-or-going-procedural-to-prevent-sql-query-co/2722#2722)) so far do a great job of showing that you *can reduce repetitiveness by writing better queries*. However even *then* you face some repetitiveness that apparently cannot be removed: This always nagged me with SQL. In "traditional" programming languages I can refactor quite a lot to minimize repetitiveness in the code, but with SQL it seems that there are no(?) tools that allow for this, except for writing a less repetitive statement to begin with.

Note that I have removed the Oracle tag again, as I would be genuinely interested whether there's no database or scripting language that allows for something more.

---

Here's one such gem that I cobbled together today. It basically reports the difference in a set of columns of a single table. Please skim through the following code, esp. the large query at the end. I'll continue below.

```
--
-- Create Table to test queries
--
CREATE TABLE TEST_ATTRIBS (
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name  VARCHAR2(300) UNIQUE,
attr1 VARCHAR2(2000),
attr2 VARCHAR2(2000),
attr3 INTEGER,
attr4 NUMBER,
attr5 VARCHAR2(2000)
);

--
-- insert some test data
--
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 1, 'Alfred',   'a', 'Foobar', 33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 2, 'Batman',   'b', 'Foobar', 66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 3, 'Chris',    'c', 'Foobar', 99, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 4, 'Dorothee', 'd', 'Foobar', 33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 5, 'Emilia',   'e', 'Barfoo', 66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 6, 'Francis',  'f', 'Barfoo', 99, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 7, 'Gustav',   'g', 'Foobar', 33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 8, 'Homer',    'h', 'Foobar', 66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values ( 9, 'Ingrid',   'i', 'Foobar', 99, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (10, 'Jason',    'j', 'Bob',    33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (12, 'Konrad',   'k', 'Bob',    66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (13, 'Lucas',    'l', 'Foobar', 99, 44, 'e');

insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (14, 'DUP_Alfred',   'a', 'FOOBAR', 33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (15, 'DUP_Chris',    'c', 'Foobar', 66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (16, 'DUP_Dorothee', 'd', 'Foobar', 99, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (17, 'DUP_Gustav',   'X', 'Foobar', 33, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (18, 'DUP_Homer',    'h', 'Foobar', 66, 44, 'e');
insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (19, 'DUP_Ingrid',   'Y', 'foo',    99, 44, 'e');

insert into TEST_ATTRIBS values (20, 'Martha',   'm', 'Bob',    33, 88, 'f');

-- Create comparison view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TA_SELFCMP as
select 
t1.id as id_1, t2.id as id_2, t1.name as name, t2.name as name_dup,
t1.attr1 as attr1_1, t1.attr2 as attr2_1, t1.attr3 as attr3_1, t1.attr4 as attr4_1, t1.attr5 as attr5_1,
t2.attr1 as attr1_2, t2.attr2 as attr2_2, t2.attr3 as attr3_2, t2.attr4 as attr4_2, t2.attr5 as attr5_2
from TEST_ATTRIBS t1, TEST_ATTRIBS t2
where t1.id <> t2.id
and t1.name <> t2.name
and t1.name = REPLACE(t2.name, 'DUP_', '')
;

-- NOTE THIS PIECE OF HORRIBLE CODE REPETITION --
-- Create comparison report
-- compare 1st attribute
select 'attr1' as Different,
id_1, id_2, name, name_dup,
CAST(attr1_1 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val1, CAST(attr1_2 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val2
from TA_SELFCMP
where attr1_1 <> attr1_2
or (attr1_1 is null and attr1_2 is not null)
or (attr1_1 is not null and attr1_2 is null)
union
-- compare 2nd attribute
select 'attr2' as Different,
id_1, id_2, name, name_dup,
CAST(attr2_1 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val1, CAST(attr2_2 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val2
from TA_SELFCMP
where attr2_1 <> attr2_2
or (attr2_1 is null and attr2_2 is not null)
or (attr2_1 is not null and attr2_2 is null)
union
-- compare 3rd attribute
select 'attr3' as Different,
id_1, id_2, name, name_dup,
CAST(attr3_1 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val1, CAST(attr3_2 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val2
from TA_SELFCMP
where attr3_1 <> attr3_2
or (attr3_1 is null and attr3_2 is not null)
or (attr3_1 is not null and attr3_2 is null)
union
-- compare 4th attribute
select 'attr4' as Different,
id_1, id_2, name, name_dup,
CAST(attr4_1 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val1, CAST(attr4_2 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val2
from TA_SELFCMP
where attr4_1 <> attr4_2
or (attr4_1 is null and attr4_2 is not null)
or (attr4_1 is not null and attr4_2 is null)
union
-- compare 5th attribute
select 'attr5' as Different,
id_1, id_2, name, name_dup,
CAST(attr5_1 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val1, CAST(attr5_2 AS VARCHAR2(2000)) as Val2
from TA_SELFCMP
where attr5_1 <> attr5_2
or (attr5_1 is null and attr5_2 is not null)
or (attr5_1 is not null and attr5_2 is null)
;
```

As you can see, the query to generate a "difference report" uses the same SQL SELECT block 5 times (could easily be 42 times!). This strikes me as absolutely brain dead (I'm allowed to say this, after all I wrote the code), but I haven't been able to find any good solution to this.

- If this would be a query in some actual application code, I *could* write a function that cobbles together this query **as a string** and then I'd execute query as a string.

  - -> Building strings is horrible and horrible to test and maintain. If the "application code" is written in a language such as PL/SQL it feels so wrong it hurts.
- Alternatively, if used from PL/SQL or its like, I'd guess there be some procedural means to make this query more maintainable.

  - -> Unrolling something that can be expressed in a single query into procedural steps just to prevent code repetition feels wrong too.
- If this query would be needed as a view in the database, then - as far as I understand - there would be no way other than to actually maintain the view definition as I posted above. (!!?)

  - -> I actually had to do some maintenance on a 2-page view definition once that wasn't far off above statement. Obviously, changing anything in this view required a regexp text search over the view definition for whether the same sub-statement had been used in another line and whether it needed changing there.

So, as the title goes - **what techniques are there to prevent having to write such abominations?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are too modest - your SQL is well and concisely written given the task you are undertaking. A few pointers:

- `t1.name <> t2.name` is always true if `t1.name = REPLACE(t2.name, 'DUP_', '')` - you can drop the former
- usually you want `union all`. `union` means `union all` then drop duplicates. It might make no difference in this case but always using `union all` is a good habit unless you explicitly want to drop any duplicates.
- if you are willing for the numeric comparisons to happen *after* casting to varchar, the following might be worth considering:

  ```
  create view test_attribs_cast as 
  select id, name, attr1, attr2, cast(attr3 as varchar(2000)) as attr3, 
         cast(attr4 as varchar(2000)) as attr4, attr5
  from test_attribs;

  create view test_attribs_unpivot as 
  select id, name, 1 as attr#, attr1 as attr from test_attribs_cast union all
  select id, name, 2, attr2 from test_attribs_cast union all
  select id, name, 3, attr3 from test_attribs_cast union all
  select id, name, 4, attr4 from test_attribs_cast union all
  select id, name, 5, attr5 from test_attribs_cast;

  select 'attr'||t1.attr# as different, t1.id as id_1, t2.id as id_2, t1.name, 
         t2.name as name_dup, t1.attr as val1, t2.attr as val2
  from test_attribs_unpivot t1 join test_attribs_unpivot t2 on(
         t1.id<>t2.id and 
         t1.name = replace(t2.name, 'DUP_', '') and 
         t1.attr#=t2.attr# )
  where t1.attr<>t2.attr or (t1.attr is null and t2.attr is not null)
        or (t1.attr is not null and t2.attr is null);
  ```

  the second view is a kind of `unpivot` operation - if you are on at least 11g you can do this more concisely with the [`unpivot`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#CHDJBHHI)clause - see [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT) for an example
- I'm say don't go down the procedural route if you can do it in SQL, but...
- Dynamic SQL is probably worth considering despite the problems you mention with testing and maintenance

--EDIT--

To answer the more general side of the question, there are techniques to reduce repetition in SQL, including:

- Views - you know about that one :)
- [Common Table Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) (see [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/WithClause.php) for example)
- individual features of the database such as `decode` (see Leigh's answer for how this can reduce repetition), [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Window_function) and [hierarchical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_query)/[recursive](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) queries to name but a few

But you can't bring OO ideas into the SQL world directly - in many cases repetition is fine if the query is readable and well-written, and it would be unwise to resort to dynamic SQL (for example) *just* to avoid repetition.

The final query including Leigh's suggested change and a CTE instead of a view could look something like this:

```
with t as ( select id, name, attr#, 
                   decode(attr#,1,attr1,2,attr2,3,attr3,4,attr4,attr5) attr
            from test_attribs
                 cross join (select rownum attr# from dual connect by rownum<=5))
select 'attr'||t1.attr# as different, t1.id as id_1, t2.id as id_2, t1.name, 
       t2.name as name_dup, t1.attr as val1, t2.attr as val2
from t t1 join test_attribs_unpivot t2 
               on( t1.id<>t2.id and 
                   t1.name = replace(t2.name, 'DUP_', '') and 
                   t1.attr#=t2.attr# )
where t1.attr<>t2.attr or (t1.attr is null and t2.attr is not null)
      or (t1.attr is not null and t2.attr is null);
```

Comment: +1, partly for `UNION ALL`. Often `UNION` without `ALL` usually results in a spool to temporary storage for the required sort operation (as 'UNION' is effectively `UNION ALL` followed by `DISTINCT` which implies a sort) so in some cases the performance difference can be huge.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative to the test_attribs_unpivot view provided by JackPDouglas <sup>(+1)</sup> that works in versions before 11g and does fewer full table scans:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_attribs_unpivot AS
   SELECT ID, Name, MyRow Attr#, CAST(
      DECODE(MyRow,1,attr1,2,attr2,3,attr3,4,attr4,attr5) AS VARCHAR2(2000)) attr
   FROM TEST_ATTRIBS 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT level MyRow FROM dual connect by level<=5);
```

His final query can be used unchanged with this view.

Comment: Much better! I think you can even drop the cast?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT rownum MyRow FROM test_attribs where rownum<=5` use `select level MyRow from dual connect by level <= 5`. You do not want all those logical gets just for creating 5 rows.

Comment: @Štefan Oravec - I had it like that, but I changed it because I wasn't sure what versions hierarchical queries were available for.  Since it has been available since at least version 8, I'll change it.

Answer (score 4):

I often encounter the similar problem to compare two versions of a table for new, deleted or changed rows. Some month ago I published a solution for SQL Server using PowerShell [here](http://poshcode.org/2390) .

To adapt it to your problem, I first create two views to separate the original from the duplicate rows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V1_TEST_ATTRIBS AS 
select * from TEST_ATTRIBS where SUBSTR(name, 1, 4) <> 'DUP_'; 

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V2_TEST_ATTRIBS AS 
select id, REPLACE(name, 'DUP_', '') name, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5 from TEST_ATTRIBS where SUBSTR(name, 1, 4) = 'DUP_';
```

and then I check the changes with

```
SELECT 1 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 FROM V1_TEST_ATTRIBS
MINUS
Select 1 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 from V2_TEST_ATTRIBS
UNION
SELECT 2 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 FROM V2_TEST_ATTRIBS
MINUS
SELECT 2 SRC ,NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 FROM V1_TEST_ATTRIBS
ORDER BY NAME, SRC;
```

From here I can find your original ids

```
Select NVL(v1.id, v2.id) id,  t.name, t.attr1, t.attr2, t.attr3, t.attr4, t.attr5 from
(
SELECT 1 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 FROM V1_TEST_ATTRIBS
MINUS
Select 1 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 from V2_TEST_ATTRIBS
UNION
SELECT 2 SRC, NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 FROM V2_TEST_ATTRIBS
MINUS
Select 2 SRC ,NAME, ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5 from V1_TEST_ATTRIBS
) t
LEFT JOIN V1_TEST_ATTRIBS V1 ON T.NAME = V1.NAME AND T.SRC = 1
LEFT JOIN V2_TEST_ATTRIBS V2 ON T.NAME = V2.NAME AND T.SRC = 2
ORDER by NAME, SRC;
```

BTW: MINUS and UNION and GROUP BY treat different NULL's as equal.
Using these operations makes the queries more elegant.

Hint for SQL Server users: MINUS is named EXCEPT there, but works similar.